# Difference between permittivities eps-opt and eps-inf?

Tags: optics, solid-state-physics, material-science, dielectric, optical-materials

Very often in materials physics we are interested in the relative permittivity at optical frequencies, which is usually denoted by $\varepsilon_\text{opt}$ or $\varepsilon_\infty$.

But I'm confused because $\varepsilon\left(\omega=\infty \right)=1$, since at high enough frequencies the medium does not have time to respond to the field and alter the allowed flux per unit charge.

So to me I feel like $\varepsilon_\text{opt}$ is very clear but that $\varepsilon_\infty$ is a stupid convention to denote optical permittivity because it should be =1 always...

But perhaps there is something I'm not understanding? Am I missing something or is it just a convention thing?

Comment: And at x-ray frequencies, the refractive index is even slightly smaller than unity.

Comment: Is your question whether it's a "stupid convention" to write $\varepsilon_\infty$ instead of $1$?